# Assigning a core to TCP polling

Tags: java, tcp, cpu-cores

We have several Java applications that run on the same Linux machine and send messages back and forth via TCP. We use a ServerSocket and Socket to create the connections. I want to reduce the latency of this communication as much as possible. It seems to be possible to assign a core on our box to do continuous TCP polling which will improve that performance. How is that done in Linux and / or Java?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. There is no way to assign a thread to a core in Java.

And assigning a single core won't improve the performance; on the contrary it will probably reduce it. I don't know exactly what you mean by 'polling' but you can't do it with Sockets: you have to use separate threads blocking in read(). If you are contemplating using `InputStream.available()` you are barking up the wrong tree altogether and should be using NIO with a Selector.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this, but it is not be portable.

What you need to do is:
 1) Find out native thread id
 2) Set affinity for the native thread

You can get the native thread id (which on linux is a process id) using unsupported classes from packages under sun.jvm.hotspot. You can link against these classes by including sa-jdi.jar (bundled with the jdk) to build path. Since I don't like idea of copying the answer from another site, you should go and read the instructions from [github](https://gist.github.com/843622)

Once you have obtained the native thread id, you should use 'taskset' command line utility to change the affinity. You can find the instructions [how to use taskset](https://serverfault.com/questions/32322/is-it-possible-to-limit-a-linux-process-so-that-it-can-only-run-on-a-particular) from another post